# Drop duplicate Pandas dataframes from a list based on a subset of columns

Tags: pandas

I have a list of dataframes named `tempDFList`.

```
type(tempDFList)
list

type(tempDFList[0])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

They have a subset of columns in common including `Previous Pivot Price` & `Pivot Price` but not all columns are the same.

How do I use something like `drop_duplicates` using default `keep='first` to ensure I don't have any frames with the same `Previous Pivot Price` & `Pivot Price` in the `tempDFList`?

Desired output is a list of dataframes that doesn't have any frames with the same `Previous Pivot Price` & `Pivot Price`.  For the sample data below only two would remain.

**Code from `df.to_dict`**

Each is a separate dataframe with one row.  These are in `tempDFList`.

```
{'Re_236_H1': {0: nan},
 'Re_382_H1': {0: nan},
 'Re_50_H1': {0: 0.8677},
 'Re_618_H1': {0: 0.8668},
 'Previous Pivot Date': {0: '2021-04-13 09:00:00'},
 'Previous Pivot Price': {0: 0.86408},
 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-04-13 13:00:00')},
 'Pivot Price': {0: 0.871180},
 'Pivot Length': {0: 0.007099}}


{'Re_236_M15': {0: nan},
 'Re_382_M15': {0: nan},
 'Re_50_M15': {0: 0.8677},
 'Re_618_M15': {0: 0.8668},
 'Previous Pivot Date': {0: '2021-04-13 09:45:00'},
 'Previous Pivot Price': {0: 0.86408},
 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-04-13 13:00:00')},
 'Pivot Price': {0: 0.871180},
 'Pivot Length': {0: 0.007099}}

{'Re_236_H4': {0: nan},
 'Re_382_H4': {0: nan},
 'Re_50_H4': {0: 0.8677},
 'Re_618_H4': {0: 0.8668},
 'Previous Pivot Date': {0: '2021-04-14 09:00:00'},
 'Previous Pivot Price': {0: 0.89408},
 'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-04-13 13:00:00')},
 'Pivot Price': {0: 0.891180},
 'Pivot Length': {0: 0.008099}}
```

Comment: Please update question with this info (if relevant): (1) It's duplicate *rows* that you want to drop? (2) "Duplicate" is assessed in terms of if a given row appears in *any* dataframe (in terms of the subset), not just the dataframe it's in, right? (3) What's the reason for not concatenating the dataframes?

Comment: @KristianCanler 1.  Drop dataframes from the list if they have duplicate `Previous Pivot Price` & `Pivot Price` values.  2. See 1.  3.  I didn't concat the dataframes as columns are different.

Comment: So, drop all dataframes that have *any* row that has the same `Previous Pivot Price` & `Pivot Price` values as *any* row in one of the other dataframes? Or drop every dataframe that contains two or more rows with the same values in those two columns? This is really important to understand what output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a simple filtering with `set` will do:

```
out = []
seen = set()
for d in tempDFList:
    t = (d["Previous Pivot Price"].iat[0], d["Pivot Price"].iat[0])
    if t not in seen:
        out.append(d)
        seen.add(t)

print(*out, sep="\n\n")
```

Prints:

```
   Re_236_H1  Re_382_H1  Re_50_H1  Re_618_H1  Previous Pivot Date  Previous Pivot Price                Date  Pivot Price  Pivot Length  df
0        NaN        NaN    0.8677     0.8668  2021-04-13 09:00:00               0.86408 2021-04-13 13:00:00      0.87118      0.007099  df

   Re_236_H4  Re_382_H4  Re_50_H4  Re_618_H4  Previous Pivot Date  Previous Pivot Price                Date  Pivot Price  Pivot Length   df
0        NaN        NaN    0.8677     0.8668  2021-04-14 09:00:00               0.89408 2021-04-13 13:00:00      0.89118      0.008099  df2
```